# Can read excel File with out any php library

Tags: php, phpexcel

There are so many excel reader libraries for php with needs zip extension enabled. With out any such library,

```
1.can we read an excel file with pure php?
2. How much effort it needs?
```

Thanks /G

Comment: You *can* read an excel file without a library, but you'll need to know the exact specification for the excel file. Overall it's **NOT EASY**. Take a look at the PHPExcel source to see how much work it is.

Comment: Of course it can be done without a library..... effectively you write the code that would be in a library yourself - libraries aren't magically created from the aether, but written by developers who need to be able to do what you need to do, but then choose to allow others to have the benefits of all the hard work that they've already done by making them freely available for other developers to download and use, so that people like you don't need to spend years writing exactly the same thing yourself

Answer (score 0):

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

The effort depends on what you want to do :-)

Comment: it's not my question, you are again with a library. I want to know how it can be done with out a library .

Comment: You know CSV. CSV is really simple. Excel is MUCH more complicated. Of course you CAN write every file format bit by bit if you want. But you won't be able to write an Excel file in appropriate time without a library. You should then first understand the complete file format which is alone very time consuming.